# Approaches to testing negative scenarios in Go

Tags: testing, go, integration-testing

I'm wondering if there's an accepted/idiomatic way of testing an unexpected behavior when working with external systems (such as databases). These are mostly cases within "if err != nil {...}", when normally the error just doesn't happen and you don't control it through the inputs.

One "right" way of doing that is probably defining an interface and a mock structure that would return error when you need it. But if I already have a significant amount of code that doesn't work with interfaces, bringing them just for the sake of testing a couple of scenarios seems tiresome.

So does anyone know and use different approaches? For example, in dynamic languages such as php and js a function/method behavior can be easily overridden with a mocking library or even manually, which is quite useful when writing tests.

Comment: Also posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/9cocm3/approaches_to_testing_negative_scenarios/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using interfaces and custom / mocked implementations for testing *is* the way to do this. If you want to test most of your code, it is worth making the switch now. If you don't want to test most of your code just a tiny part of it, then what's the point of even bothering with the test? They won't ensure you of anything, on the contrary, they will give you the–false–illusion that "everything" is fine.

If you don't want to use and mock interfaces, another way would be to mock the database server itself, but let's face it, it would be even more work.

Just use interfaces. It's never too late to refactor. It is something always worth doing on the long run.

Also note that you can do this "switch" gradually. Just create an interface that contains the functionality used by the code you want to test. You don't need to "touch" the rest of your code. Change the testable code to use the interface, which then you can mock in your tests. This is easy in Go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It sounds reasonable and I had similar thoughts, but was under the impression that easier (and maybe dirtier) methods should exist.